# Any known problems after Tomcat-upgrade using oracle locator?

Tags: spatial-database, java, oracle-dbms, tomcat

After trying to upgrade from Tomcat 5.5.28 to 5.5.29 or above I ran into a strange problem.
We use a linux based gis system using an Oracle EE DB (without spatial license).

### Problem

After the upgrade we get for some actions the following java-error:

```
java.io.IOException: org.hibernatespatial.helper.FinderException: Couldn't get at the OracleSpatial Connection object from the PreparedStatement.
```

I was able to pin the cause down to the DBCP library. Up until Tomcat 5.5.28 this was 1.2.2 after that it was upgraded to 1.3 (which is technically the same as 1.4).

The DBCP library is the database abstraction layer between Tomcat and the ojdbc6.jar (as far as I understood).

If I do a downgrade to dbcp 1.2.2 after the Tomcat-Upgrade everything works again without problems.

Has anyone encountered this out there, too? The DBCP-developers can't help, since the java exception is not directly related to dbcp (which is strange, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the changelog for dbcp it seems that the issue you are experiencing might be related to the changes introduced by [DBCP-11](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DBCP-11) in dbcp 1.3/1.4 (changelog is the same for both versions).

Since the PreparedStatement is now wrapped by a DBCP object (a DelegatingStatement to be exact) the ConnectionFinder code is unable to invoke its constructor.

At this point you have two options:

1. try to upgrade hibernatespatial to the latest version (changelog from 1.1 says this issue should have been fixed in [HIBSPA-68](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/jira/browse/HIBSPA-68))
2. report this analysis to the hibernatespatial mantainers and have them fix the issue

Comment: Great. I'll post that to the DBCP and Tomcat developers. You propably hit the mark.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the issue should be reported to the hibernatespatial developers *IF* upgrading to the latest version of hibernatespatial does not work.

Comment: I have to get this down to developement. Hybernate uses DBCP which is part of Tomcat, but itselv is not part of Tomcat. So this is neither a a DBCP nor a Tomcat problem. I`ll post the results here.